# how can i show usercontrol in other usercontrol C#

Tags: c#

how can I show user control in other user control
I need simple code :|
I was searching but didn't find :<

i was trying

```
 this.Hide();
 cross2 uc = new cross2();
 uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
 this.Controls.Add(uc);
 uc.Visible = true;
```

Comment: You added something to something invisible (you called Hide). All children of the hidden control will also be hidden even if you change their visible flag. If you want to see cross2 add it to a container also visible.